# Openlayers in div with zoom style property

Tags: css, zooming, openlayers

I have a website in which a container div is set up so that it will fit the browser window.
This is done by the css style "zoom" attribute.

Inside this container div I have the div for the map of openlayers.
Now the problem is that this zoom of the container div ruins the size of the openlayers map.
Its not done with map.updatesize() because the actual size of the divs doesn't change with different window sizes. So the div of the map has the correct size.
But the map that is displayed seems to be bigger than the div it is displayed in. 
In the end the map looks blurry and zooming in and out in the map is not done to the mouse location but a little bit to the side.

So, any ideas how I can fix this?
Fyi I tried with ol3 and ol5. No difference.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got it.

First I added the reversed zoom factor as zoom for the canvas div.

Then after loading the map I change the size of the map with the zoom factor back so its position and all will fit in the old place.

```
        var OldWidth = parseInt(MapElement.style.width);
        MapElement.style.width = ZoomFactor*OldWidth+"px";

        var OldHeight = parseInt(MapElement.style.height);
        MapElement.style.height = ZoomFactor*OldHeight+"px";

        var OldLeft = parseInt(MapElement.style.left);
        MapElement.style.left = ZoomFactor*OldLeft+"px";

        var OldTop = parseInt(MapElement.style.top);
        MapElement.style.top = ZoomFactor*OldTop+"px";`
```

Done. :-)

Comment: Fantastic answer - One note is that the "canvas div" is the container holding the #map from openlayers, not the actual canvas element inside the map

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix this through css position and width/height, not zoom. Try this:

```
html, body, #divContainer, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot change the width and height of the #divContainer. Its all about the zoom now. The mainContainer is not in my responsibility. All I get is the zoom value. And I hope I can just use this value and zoom the map back to its original width and height. But I didn't find any possibility yet.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to fit your map into the container div that you have no control over. Is it only "your map" in this div, or do you share it with other components? If you're the only client in there, you can at least set the divContainer's padding to 0px and your map's margin to 0px.

I humbly suggest that you check the css box model:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it as you can see on my answer. The boxmodel is not helping me here. padding and margin is all fine. Its just the problem, that the width and height of the map canvas is not corresponding to the drawn width and height and therefor it looks blurry because its zoomed. But I fixed it now.